# Fetching a file as a String response using Apache CXF

Tags: rest, cxf

I have a simple REST client using the Apache CXF library. Here is the code snippet:

```
    val wc = WebClient.create(address(host, port) + "/" + resource).`type`("text/plain")
    requestParam match {
      case Some(reqParams) => reqParams.foreach((param: (String, String)) => {
        wc.query(param._1, param._2)
      })
      case None => wc
    }

    println("Acturl url is " + wc.getCurrentURI)

    wc.get(classOf[String])
  }
```

What I'm trying to fetch is a simple file named test.txt. I want to render this as a plain String and that is what I do at the last line on the code snippet above. But I get the following error:

```
javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException was thrown.
javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.convertToWebApplicationException(AbstractClient.java:462)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:860)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:831)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:394)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.get(WebClient.java:573)
```

How can I return the call to a GET endpoint as a plain String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a bit stupid. My original code actually worked and returned a String that I wanted!

```
wc.get(classOf[String])
```